# Navigationcontroller is hidden after pushing viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, hide, xcode5

I'm working on an app and I face a problem with `UINavigationcontroller`.

First in the app delegate I check if the user is logged in, if so I take him to Main screen, if notI take him to the login screen.

This is my code:

```
    UINavigationController *diabetesNavigationController = [UINavigationController alloc];
LoginViewController *loginPage = [[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
MainViewController *mainPage = [[MainViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];


if ([DataStore instance].userIsLoggedIn)
    diabetesNavigationController = [diabetesNavigationController initWithRootViewController:mainPage];
else
    diabetesNavigationController = [diabetesNavigationController initWithRootViewController:loginPage];


NSDictionary *navbarTitleTextAttributes = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setBarTintColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance]setTitleTextAttributes:navbarTitleTextAttributes];

[self.window setRootViewController:diabetesNavigationController];
```

The problem when the user logs out, he goes back to loginscreen but without the `navigationcontroller`.

I made something in MainViewController, which is this:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    self.navigationItem.title = @"Diabetes";
    UIBarButtonItem *settingButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"burger.png"]
                                                               style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                              target:self
                                                              action:@selector(onBurger:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = settingButton;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
}
```

So when I logout the user, with this code:

```
LoginViewController *loginPage = [[LoginViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:loginPage, nil] animated:YES];
```

I get to the login screen but without `Navigationcontroller`. I tried to set Hidden property to NO in all view delegates, but it still has this issue.

Comment: did you try in - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated { [super viewWillAppear:animated]; [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:animated];{

Comment: Yes I did, still the same issue

Comment: Yes I did, still no working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
UIWindow *window = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
LoginViewController * loginPage = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: loginPage];
[window.rootViewController presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Let me know if it works.. :)

Comment: Nop, it didn't work.
The problem that Um dealing with Navigation item to put the menu item but the one who is responsiple for pushing and pulling is navigation controller it self not the navigation item.
and when I try to change the navigation item from the navigation controller it doesn't affect.

Comment: The problem that um passing navigation controller to normal view controllers.

Comment: ViewController can't hold a navigation controller.

Comment: um initialise the navigation controller with view controller.
and put navigation item inside it.